# Persisting a Protocol Buffer Model with JDO on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, protocol-buffers

we are building an Android app that communicates with a Java App Engine Server via Protocol Buffers. We use JDO as the persistence mechanism on the server.

My question is how to persist objects in the App Engine database. It seems like the only way to do it is the create two classes for each model: one model which is generated from the .proto file and a second class that wraps the first class and provides JDO annotations, additional methods etc. This seems rather cumbersome to me and I am wondering what the best practice regarding this might be. Is there a way to avoid this duplication (JPA for instance allows to specify the persistence annotations in external XML files, but we would rather avoid JPA on App Engine because of the poor documentation)?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine's datastore only stores Model Protocol Buffers. If the protocol buffer your client sends you is a Model PB, you could store it directly by poking it into the low level APIs. If it's any other sort of PB, you either need to convert it (manually) into an Entity, or you need to serialize it and store it in a binary property of the entity. Which of those you choose depends on how you need to query the stored object.

Either way, JDO is probably a poor choice - you should look into Objectify, or use the low-level API directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "Model Protocol Buffers"? Is that the type of protobuf used internally by App Engine? If so, is it exposed anywhere?  I'm actually using objectify but it doesn't support protobufs either. (You either have to manually serialize/deserialize or convert to a class that Objectify can embed.)